# How come there are more cookies in the "Cookie" request header than the number of cookies that were set in the "set-cookie" response header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, http-headers, httprequest

I am a rookie at webscraping, and thus my knowledge of http requests is shallow. When inspecting certain requests that I make to a website for example, such as adding to cart, in the dev tools,
**it shows that the request "Cookie" header has way more values in it** that were set by the "set-cookie" response header.

**How does this work?**

More specifically, a cookie in the "set-cookie" response header will contain the id for a cart, but when looking at all of the values in the "Cookie" request header, that cart id will be there, but there are also other cookies referring to "checkout session lookup" and "checkout session token".

Yet, **these cookies weren't set in the "set-cookie" header of the response, so how did they get there?**

Let's say I wanted to grab the full "Cookie" value of the request header with all of the cookies included, and not just the ones in the "set-cookie" response header, **is there a way to do this?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have something to do with the JavaScript on this page. For example, the code below can set a new cookie:
`document.cookie="username=John Doe";`

So, a cookie can be sent not only by request head.

To get full cookies, I think you may need a headless browser.